# How to show $\int_{B_1} \frac{(p|\omega|)^m}{m!} \le 2^{-m} \Rightarrow \int_{B_1} e^{p_0 |\omega|} dx \le C$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Assume $\omega \in H^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$, if there is a constant $p>0$ depend on $n$ such that
$$
\int_{B_1} \frac{(p|\omega|)^m}{m!} \le 2^{-m},~~~~~~m=2,3,...
$$
where $B_1$ is unit ball. Then how to show there is constant $p_0 >0, C>0$  such that
$$
\int_{B_1} e^{p_0 |\omega|} dx \le C
$$

This problem is from the proof of Harnack inequality (of weak solution of Laplace equation) in a book written by Chinese, I can't understand this step, so ask here, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral at the beginning does not have a differential, but the later one has $dx$.  I'll assume both have the same.

$e^{p|\omega|}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(p|\omega|)^m}{m!}$

$\int_{B_1}e^{p|\omega|}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \int_{B_1}\frac{(p|\omega|)^m}{m!}\le \frac{1}{2}+\int_{B_1}(1+p|\omega|)=C$.

Note $\frac{1}{2}=\sum_{m=2}^\infty 2^{-m}$  The last integral is dependent on $n$.

Comment: Haha, I'm a little stupid.

Comment: Seemly, the constant $C$ is dependent $\omega$,  but  on the book, it is not dependent on $\omega$,   how to deal it ?

Comment: @lanse7pty The lower power terms can always be controlled by Holder's inequality. For example $\int_{B_1} |\omega|\,dx \le |B_1|^{1/2}\left(\int_{B_1} |\omega|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}$, where, $|B_1|$ is the volume of $B_1$.

Comment: @r9m  Thanks. I really be a little stupid...